# Remove And Show TD using script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, removeclass

Good Day I'm using Asp.net for my website and I want to remove and Hide and specific td with class attribute

here is my html code

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="1"> 1 </td>
<td class="1"> 1 </td>
<td class="2"> 2 </td>
<td class="2"> 2 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now i have 2 button in my website named btn1 and btn2

if btn1 is click
i want to remove ALL class with 1 and show only class with 2

And

if btn2 is click
i want to remove ALL class with 2 and show only class with 1

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: That's great. What effort have you made in solving the problem, beyond posting this question?

Comment: "remove _and_ hide"? I take it you mean that you just want to hide them so that if the other button is clicked you show them again and hide the others? (If you actually _remove_ them they're gone, you'd need to re-insert them into the DOM to show them again.)

Comment: What do you mean by DOM?

Comment: Read the answers below, they all show you how to achieve that. As many of them uses jQuery you need to include it's library: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>. Put that inside your <head> tag, and enjoy using jQuery.

Comment: DOM stands for Document Object Model, which is kind of the logical structure representing the current document displayed by the browser. You could think of it as a sort of tree data structure that the browser builds as it parses the original source HTML. When you interact with the page from Javascript you do so using DOM methods (or via a library like jQuery which itself uses DOM methods). For more information read [what the W3C has to say about it](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html) or Google it.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mAMMH/1/)

include script

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="bnt1"/>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="bnt2"/>
```

**js**

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('td.1').show();
    $('td.2').hide();
});
$('#btn2').click(function() {
    $('td.2').show();
    $('td.1').hide();
});
```

References

[id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

[class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `.hide()` and `.show()` functions, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('.1').hide();
            $('.2').show();
        });

        $('#Button2').click(function () {
            $('.2').hide();
            $('.1').show();
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="1">1</td>
        <td class="1">1</td>
        <td class="2">2</td>
        <td class="2">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="Button1" value="Button 1" />
<input type="button" id="Button2" value="Button 2" />
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mAMMH/).